# Password Encryption and Decryption with Jasypt and random salt

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

Hi I have a Java application. I want to use Jasypt to encrypt and decrypt the passwords with random salt generated based on size and algorithm.

This is what I want to achieve.

1. Create a random salt.
2. Encrypt the password with the salt.
3. Save the salt and encrypted password for the user.

**I want the salt size, algorithm to be given as input.**

The reason why I want decryption is that, I have some configuration files created for the application and some values are passwords that I want to save as encrypted in the file and decrypt it when I want to use it.

I have [this Java class](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode) which creates salt and then creates the hash code and I could use it for validating user (I can save salt and hascode instead of encrypted password.). I changed it some and created a method to create random salt in that example. But there is no decryption method.

That's why I choose Jasypt. But I havn't seen any proper example of how to use it.

I tried following and always it returns same salt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomSaltGenerator saltGenerator = new RandomSaltGenerator();
    byte[] salt = saltGenerator.generateSalt(24);
    System.out.println(salt);
}
```

Can anybody provide a proper example or how to use it in my own way? I want to achieve what [Jasypt have mentioned in their article](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html). But there are no codes available.

Answer (score 3):

This article about [password encryption](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html) with Jasypt describes standard best practices of storing encrypted user passwords with **one-way encryption**. Once you've stored a password using such techniques, there is now way to decrypt it.

If you need to encrypt and decrypt passwords for application configuration, you should consider using the [StandardPBEStringEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html) provided by Jasypt (or whatever provider best fits your data type). This [page](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-texts.html) contains good explanation and example code.

Even better, Jasypt provides first class support for [encrypted application configuration](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html) using .properties files (also with good support for Spring).